# Drop specific rows in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to drop two problematic lines into the dataframe but it gives me an error.
(I guess it is very simple but my level of programming is very very low)

Code :

```
import pandas as pd
members = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")
```

The error :

```
members = members.drop(members[(members["injury_height_metres"]>8850)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the index when dropping rows:

```
members = members.drop(members[(members["injury_height_metres"]>8850)].index)
```